# Trying to isolate certain array items and evaluate them for equality

Tags: c++

I've got an fstream input file that has [N] lines or items. I've written code to decide which items are triangles and which are rectangles and which are circles. I've got to isolate just the triangle items and then compare them to see if they are equal to +/- 0.1 the area of all the other triangle items. Then I have to cout the equal pairs of items as uppercase char letters.

Here's my code so far but it's not working correctly. It's giving me the last item in the array plus one that doesn't exist. How do I fix this?

```
// ........................................................
// 4. List any triangular blocks that are the same size.
// ........................................................

float TAE = 0.0;
float ItmM = 0.0;

for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
{
  if (btype[i] == Triangles)
  {
    TA[i] = (0.5 * (D[i] * E[i]));

    TAE = TA[i+1];

    if ((TA[i] - 0.1) <= TAE <= (TA[i] + 0.1))
    {
      TAE = TA[i];
      ItmN = i;
      ItmM = i+1;
    }
  }
}
cout << "4. Triangular blocks that are the same size = "
     << (char)('A' + ItmN) << "&" << (char)('A' + ItmM)
     << endl;
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code in a debugger?

Comment: why not use a bit more self-documenting names, like

Comment: I don't understand what a debugger is. The code compiles fine.

Comment: Really ? An a<=b<=c comparison ? Edit: REALLY?! :) ...

Comment: I changed it (if (TA[i] - 0.1 < TAE && TAE < TA[i] + 0.1)

Answer (score 0):

First, when you don comparison, you don't write `a<b<c`. The correct one should be `a<b && b<c`. The compiler should give a warning here.

And when you do `TAE=TA[i+1]`, I guess from your code that `TA[i+1]` is not assigned yet, which can contain an arbitrary value.

And why use `float` for `ItmM`? From your program, you can use an `int`.

Comment: THanks, I changed the way that the comparison is written and changed ItmM to an int. However, I still don't understand how to do the comparison. I've tried several iterations and all have failed. Now my algorithm is telling me that A&A are the two triangles that equal each other. It's supposed to be E&L. numbers 5 and 12 in my array.